# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am making a movie app clone, but I am getting this error:

> "Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jiTW.png)

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { baseUrl } from '../constants/movie'
import { Movie } from '../typing'

interface Props {
  netflixOriginals: Movie[]
}

function Banner({ netflixOriginals }: Props) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setMovie(
      netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]
    )
  }, [netflixOriginals])

  console.log(movie)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='absolute top-0 left-0 h-[95vh] w-screen'>
      <Image
          src={`${baseUrl}${movie?.backdrop_path || movie?.poster_path}`}
          layout="fill"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default Banner
```

Comment: can you console.log netflixoriginals right before the setmovie call ?

Comment: `netflixOriginals` is null or undefined. You have to handle that case instead of assuming it will always be an array

Answer (score 0):

`netflixOriginals` doesn't seem to be defined by you.
Use optional chaining so that `length` property is not referenced if `netflixOriginals` is undefined.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setMovie(
      netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals?.length)]
    )
  }, [netflixOriginals])
```

Comment: If `netflixOriginals` is null or undefined, then `Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals?.length)` will be `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

`netflixOriginals` can be passed in as null. Defaulting it to an empty array would help but you still need to make sure you handle the case where the array has no values, meaning you have no shows to display.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { baseUrl } from '../constants/movie'
import { Movie } from '../typing'

interface Props {
  netflixOriginals: Movie[]
}

function Banner({ netflixOriginals = [] }: Props = {}) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie | null>(null)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setMovie(
      netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]
    )
  }, [netflixOriginals])


  
  return (
   {
   movie 
   ? <div>
      <div className='absolute top-0 left-0 h-[95vh] w-screen'>
      <Image
          src={`${baseUrl}${movie?.backdrop_path || movie?.poster_path}`}
          layout="fill"
        />
      </div>
     </div>
   : <div>There are no movies</div>
    )
}

export default Banner
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `netflixOriginals` is being passed in initially as `null`. You could test for a valid list before calling `setMovie()`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (netflixOriginals?.length) {
      setMovie(
        netflixOriginals[Math.floor(Math.random() * netflixOriginals.length)]
      )
    }
  }, [netflixOriginals])
```

This will also prevent your code from calling `setMovie()` when the array is empty.

The optional chaining operator (`?.`) will keep the first check of the length property from throwing an error if `netflixOriginals` is not defined.